# ChartJS Stacked Group with labels on each bars

Tags: php, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I am totally lost on how to achieve this [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/samples/charts/bar.html) with my json result

```
[
   "[{\"label\":\"Meal\",\"value\":\"Rice\"},{\"label\":\"Location\",\"value\":\"VI\"},{\"label\":\"Payment\",\"value\":\"50k\"}]",
   "[{\"label\":\"Meal\",\"value\":\"Beans\"},{\"label\":\"Location\",\"value\":\"VI\"},{\"label\":\"Payment\",\"value\":\"35k\"}]",
   "[{\"label\":\"Meal\",\"value\":\"Rice\"},{\"label\":\"Location\",\"value\":\"Maryland\"},{\"label\":\"Payment\",\"value\":\"50k\"}]",
   "[{\"label\":\"Meal\",\"value\":\"Bread\"},{\"label\":\"Location\",\"value\":\"Maryland\"},{\"label\":\"Payment\",\"value\":\"150k\"}]",
   "[{\"label\":\"Meal\",\"value\":\"Rice\"},{\"label\":\"Location\",\"value\":\"Maryland\"},{\"label\":\"Payment\",\"value\":\"35k\"}]"
]
```

Ideally I want to show `Meal` has 3 Rice, 1 Beans, 1 Bread and same goes for `Location` and `Payment`[image: chartjs-bar]

Any help or directly will greatly be appreciated

Comment: use destroy() method before make chart.i also got previous data in chart after filtration.

Answer (score 0):

The correct method to use, in order to be able to draw another chart on the same canvas, is `.destroy()`. You must call it on the previously created chart object. You may also use the same variable for both charts

```
var grapharea = document.getElementById("barChart").getContext("2d");

var myChart = new Chart(grapharea, { type: 'bar', data: barData, options: barOptions });

myChart.destroy();

myChart = new Chart(grapharea, { type: 'radar', data: barData, options: barOptions })
```

Comment: Not sure how this would work ... you have a real case-study please?